# js object sending through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have spent two days trying to get the issue resolved, but can't get it done.

I am sending session stored in browser through jQuery AJAX to PHP function so that to save the data to Wordpress db.

in session Storage data is stored like this -

[image]

so this without success:

```
var dataStorage = JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));


       $.ajax({
            url: "https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: 'globalvar='+dataStorage+'&action=myfunction',
             dataType: "json"  
        }).done(function (response) {});
```

the PHP function is:

```
if (!function_exists('myfunction')) {

function myfunction() {
    

     
  $object = $_POST['globalvar'];
     
     $decoded_object = json_decode($object);

       //wordpress update db                 
      update_post_meta('42393', 'menu_items_list',  $menu_make_arr);
        
 }

     
             add_action('wp_ajax_myfunction', 'myfunction');
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunction',  'myfunction');
}
```

I get null in db like this

[image]

Comment: Have you checked what is sent to PHP with the browser developer tools? Note that when you send data as a string you should [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) it: `data: 'globalvar='+encodeURIComponent(sessionStorage)+'&action=myfunction'`

Comment: Change your variable name sessionStorage to some other like dataStorage or whatever you want. var dataStorage = JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));

Comment: Yes. A logical name for the `sessionStorage` variable would be `shoppingCart`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ,  i have added encodeURI but still get NULL, how can i check what is sent to PHP ?

Comment: See: [What are browser developer tools?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) You cannot write code without it.

Comment: Just a tip, but when you're programming you need to be precise. For instance `encodeURI` isn't the same as `encodeURIComponent`. I used that specifically because `encodeURI` doesn't encode all the characters in your JSON, for instance the colon and comma.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is what i get in console under the 'response' - "\\\"[{\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\u0427\u0438\u0437\u0431\u0451\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0440 \u0445\u0430\u043b\u044f\u043b\u044c\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"price\\\\\\\":259,\\\\\\\"count\\\\\\\":1},{\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\u0411\u0451\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0440 \u0441\u0442\u0435\u0439\u043a \u0445\u0430\u043b\u044f\u043b\u044c\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"price\\\\\\\":299,\\\\\\\"count\\\\\\\":1}]\\\""0

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the sessionStorage already stores a string, and the var you are saving into, shouldn't be called sessionStorage, because it hides the name of the original sessionStorage. Also avoid using "var" alltogether, use const and let.

```js
const shoppingCart = sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart')
```

Secondly, the data you are sending is URL encoded into the body of the HTTP request (and the JSON part probably gets scewed up).

```js
encodeURIComponent(shoppingCart)
```

My recommendation would be to encode everything in JSON. Since you are already "lying to the protocol" with the dataType: "json" you provided (your actual data is application/x-www-form-urlencoded not application/json).

JS:

```js
const shoppingCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'))

$.ajax({
  url: "https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    globalvar: shoppingCart,
    action: "myfunction"
  }),
  dataType: "json"  
}).done((res) => {});
```

PHP ():

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$body = json_decode($json);

$func = $body->action;
$data = $body->globalvar;
```

Comment: dont understand php part , tried it but get ajax error 400

Comment: I agree that posting JSON is a good idea.

Comment: Which part requires clarification?

$func will contain the string "myfunction"
$data will contain the shopping cart object

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('php://input') this one , but anyways a get ajax error 400,   in response header is 0

Comment: file_get_contents('php://input') takes the body of the request and returns it as a string.
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); this turnes the aformentioned string into a PHP object/map that you can use like your regular old JS object.


Btw this isn't EVERYTHING you should have in your php. Just use $func and $data instead of $_POST['action'] $_POST['globalvar']

Answer (score 1):

To read `application/json` in php we can use `php://input`

So the code will be like this

```
function myfunction() {
        $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $json = json_decode($rawData);

        $object = $json->globalvar;
```

To send `application/json` from browse to php we can use `JSON.stringify`

So the code will be like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify([{"name": "name1"},{"name": "name2"}]));

var dataStorage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));

$.ajax({
    url: "test1.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "globalvar": dataStorage, "action" : "myfunction"}),
    dataType: "json"  
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: This exact answer has already been posted here 38 minutes ago. What does your answer add? Of course you are free to post any answer you want, just wondering if you didn't notice this?

Comment: no I did not notice, I was typing the code in Notepad++ and xampp

Comment: Well, it is a good answer. 

Comment: @DickensAS Ajax error 400 , header response 0

Comment: it should be related to wordpress, so we need to understand how to satisfy wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I think sessionStorage is a reserved keyword so it is creating the issue. You can debug the variable state. This code works for me.

```js
var dataStorage = JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));

$.post({
  url: "https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: 'globalvar=' + encodeURIComponent(dataStorage) + '&action=myfunction',
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function(response) {});
```

PHP Code - Just removed a few lines for debugging

```
if (!function_exists('myfunction')) {

    function myfunction()
    {
        $object = $_POST['globalvar'];
        $decoded_object = json_decode($object);
        print_r($decoded_object);
    }

    myfunction();
}
```

Comment: @Shoaib_Ijaz tried this one but still get NULL

Comment: Check the Network tab of your Dev Tools. You can debug the request that you are sending.

Comment: You code says you're posting JSON, but you're actually posting an URL query string. Will that work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the provided PHP code, Now added the PHP code as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects to fix/check:

## 1. Is the function defined as you want?

Your

```
if (!function_exists('myfunction')) {
    //...
}
```

Checks whether `myfunction` exists and only executes he inner block if a `function` by this name does not already exist. You will need to make sure that your `function` ends up existing and some older `function` by the same name does not prevent this `function` from being created.

## 2. Is your JSON in proper format?

You are `json_decode`'ing your session data and on the database level you would need to store a value like

```
'[{"name":"том","price":259,"count":1},{"name":"жак","price":299,"count":1}]'
```

into your record. Try to make sure that the way you are storing your JSON is valid in Wordpress.

## 3. Check the Network tab of your Dev Tools

You will need to make sure that your request is being sent properly and the JSON you expect to be sent is being sent after all.

## 4. Make sure myfunction is being executed after all

It would not hurt to add some logging to this `function` to see that it's being executed.

Comment: 1) Function doesnt exist anywhere else. 2) when i dont json_decode it i get "[{\"name\":\"том\",\"price\":259,\"count\":1},{\"name\":\"жак\",\"price\":299,\"count\":1}]" 4) its execute since i can get back the variable to js and console log it

Comment: @Andy what happens when you execute it without `json_decode`?

Comment: i get this in my db   "[{\"name\":\"том\",\"price\":259,\"count\":1},{\"name\":\"жак\",\"price\":299,\"count\":1}]"

Comment: @Andy how did you initialize `$menu_make_arr`?